# Error loading interface lanplus (ipmitool on CentOS)

Tags: local-area-network, electrical-power, ipmi, interface

I'm having trouble specifying the lanplus interface for the ipmitool program.  I issue a command such as `ipmitool -I lanplus -U USER -P PASSWORD -H 10.16.0.253 sol activate` and I am given the following error: `Error loading interface lanplus`.  When I try the command: `ipmitool -h`, lanplus does not appear on the list of interfaces.  This makes me think I have not configured my ipmitool installation correctly (I used yum to install OpenIPMI and OpenIPMI-tools) or I am missing a package.  What am I missing to get the lanplus interface to be recognized by ipmitool? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well reconfiguring and making from source did the trick (used the latest on sourceforge). Lanplus is available now.